# Phpstorm cursor jumping back constantly at long lines

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, cursor-position

When I have a long line and want to type text at the end, the cursor constantly jumping back to the middle of the text, for example:
from here: [image] to here: [image].
Is it a bug or a feature ? How can I turn it off ? My PHPstorm version is 4.0.2 (#PS-117.501)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this is the ideaVIM plugin. When you disable it, it works just fine !
Here is he issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85578

Answer (score 1):

It may be font specific bug, try to change the font in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts`.

Comment: tried to change various font settings back and forth but doesn't help :(

Comment: What OS/Java versions do you use?

Comment: OS X 10.7.4, java 1.6.0_33.
I made a bugreport on Youtrack.